# Margin-bottom for container with span6 div's inside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two `div class="span6"` (in the same row) inside a container. Now I want to give a `margin-bottom` to the container, but since those `div class="span6"` are floating it is like they are not there, so the height of the container is 0..what is your advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just add `overflow: hidden;` to the container - [this will prevent it's height from collapsing.](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)